# What is the point of collecting coins after all upgrades?

Tags: temple-run-2

In Temple Run 2, collected coins can be used to upgrade powers. After all the functionalities are upgraded fully, **what is the point of collecting coins?**

Answer (score 3):

After all the abilities are upgraded, there are really just two possible other uses for coins:

1. routinely use the headstart each run
2. unlock new characters for novelty value

Besides those, coins will just accumulate generally at faster rate than you can use them.